# Avoiding ConcurrentModificationException in Event Bus

Tags: java, concurrency, crash, hashset

I have a `EventBus` system which clients can at will join / leave.

The `EventBus` is using `HashSet` to keep track of clients, and when a message is broadcasted, it's delivered to all registered clients.

```
// clients - HashSet of clients.
// message - event object to be delivered

for (Object client : clients) {
    sendTo(client, message);    
}
```

I know this is inefficient, but I don't know how to improve it.

The problem is that the clients can react to some events by disconnecting from the bus. Let's take it as a fact, it must be possible.

They call this method:

```
public void unsubscribe(Object client)
{
    clients.remove(client);
}
```

And then, of course, I get an error:

```
[!E!] java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
[!E!]   at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(LinkedHashMap.java:390)
[!E!]   at java.util.LinkedHashMap$KeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:401)
[!E!]   at mightypork.utils.control.bus.EventChannel.doBroadcast(EventChannel.java:56)
[!E!]   at mightypork.utils.control.bus.EventChannel.broadcast(EventChannel.java:48)
[!E!]   at mightypork.utils.control.bus.EventBus.broadcast(EventBus.java:82)
[!E!]   at mightypork.rogue.App.shutdown(App.java:133)
[!E!]   at mightypork.rogue.App.start(App.java:87)
[!E!]   at mightypork.rogue.App.main(App.java:72)
[!E!]
```

Not cool, right?

Any idea to fix this?

Comment: Okay I think I was faster than the community here xD
Solved by using `CopyOnWriteArraySet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is mark clients which should be removed and then remove them in "safe" place.

```
public void unsubscribe(Object client)
{
    clientsToRemove.add(client);
}
```

And in code something like this :

```
for (Object client : clients) {
    sendTo(client, message);    
}
client.removeAll(clientsToRemove);
```

Comment: But what if `client.removeAll` is executing and new entries are added to that list?

Comment: adding them the same way as removing

Comment: Solved it in a similar way, have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844619/take-a-snapshot-of-a-set

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) for this.

With a LinkedList, you can use its iterator to loop through it, and use that same iterator to remove the object from the LinkedList.

Example:

```
List<Client> clients = new LinkedList<>();
Iterator it = clients.iterator();

while (it.hasNext())
{
  Client client = (Client) it.next();
  sendTo(client, message);
  it.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an Iterator, you can modify a collection during iteration. For more information, see The Collection Interface tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html

Comment: True, but entirely unrelated to the problem.

Comment: Even if I iterated using an iterator (instead of enhanced for-each loop), the clients would have no way to call i.remove() or whatever you had in mind. It's an entirely different object with no access to the loop.

Comment: @MightyPork ah apologies, I understand where you are coming from now.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by using `CopyOnWriteArraySet` instead of `HashSet`.

Thanks for the suggestions anyway, it can help someone else.